# Jquery ajax clear before reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I know this is a topic discussed here many times, but none of the solution of the site have helped me....

I'm having two nav items and both of them load two different PHP files by using jquery ajax. I'm using jquery mobile.
My problem is that whenever i click on the other nav item the other one doesn't clear itself, so basically i get div on top of div. 
I've tried `.html("");` but hasn't worked for me so far.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
      <ul>
          <li><a class="classloader1">Upcoming</a></li>
          <li><a class="classloader2">History</a></li>
      </ul> 
</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
 $(".classloader1").click(function(){
     $("#content").load("get.php");
 })
    $(".classloader2").click(function(){
     $("#content").load("history.php");
 })
```

Comment: try the long form of jquery

Comment: try $("#content").empty().load("get.php");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try a different tab structure like

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="classloader one">Upcoming</a></li>
        <li><a class="classloader two">History</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

where both elements share the `classloader` *class* name. Then I would use jQuery `.html()` to load the content but returning the specific file depending on the clicked tab like :

```
 $(".classloader").on("click", function (event) {
     var file = $(event.target).hasClass("one") ? "get.php" : "history.php";
     $("#content").html(function () {
         return $(this).load(file);
     });
 });
```

If you have more than two tabs, you could use a `switch` statement to set the value of the `file` var.

See **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loadContentAjax_05mar14.html)**

**UPDATE** : see **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loadContentAjax_05mar15.html)** using jQuery mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! unfortunately i still get the same result with this code.

Comment: @Gabby_987 : really? I added a [demo](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loadContentAjax_05mar14.html) to my answer

Comment: yeah it's not working... so maybe problem is somewhere else? It started when i used jquery mobile. Could it be because of the loop in my php files?

Comment: @Gabby_987 : I setup a demo with jQuery mobile and works good to me, does my demo work for you? http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/loadContentAjax_05mar15.html

Comment: @Gabby_987 maybe you need to validate your document, it may have a syntax error somewhere